# Objective-C methods not running

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, object

I'm messing around with using objects to launch background threads, however when I call an objects method to call the method that will spawn a background thread, nothing happens. I'm a bit puzzled as to why, and it looks like the -init function isn't even being called. Anyways, here's what I have:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Threader.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong) Thread* threadedObject;
- (IBAction)StartBackgroundThreadButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Threader.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _threadedObject = [[Threader alloc]init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)StartBackgroundThreadButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Clicked.");
    [_threadedObject RunInBackground];


}
@end
```

Threader.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Threader : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) bool IsFinishedRunning;
@property(nonatomic) bool IsThreading;

//Constructor and Destructor
-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;

-(void)RunInBackground;

-(void)WaitForTenSeconds;

@end
```

Threader.m

```
#import "Threader.h"

@implementation Threader

//constructor
-(id)init{
    [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        _IsFinishedRunning = NO;
        _IsThreading = NO;
    }


    return self;
}



//destructor
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}


//Runs a thread in the background
-(void)RunInBackground{
    NSLog(@"Initiating thread...");
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(WaitForTenSeconds) withObject:nil];

}

//Waits for 10 seconds, then sets IsFinishedRunning to YES
-(void)WaitForTenSeconds{
    NSLog(@"Starting to run in the background.");
    _IsThreading = YES;
    sleep(10);
    _IsFinishedRunning = YES;

    NSLog(@"Finished running in the background.");

}


@end
```

When I run the program, this is my output(I clicked the button a few times)
2013-05-17 15:30:57.267 ThreadedObjects Clicked.
2013-05-17 15:30:59.003 ThreadedObjects Clicked.
2013-05-17 15:30:59.259 ThreadedObjects Clicked.
2013-05-17 15:30:59.443 ThreadedObjects Clicked.
2013-05-17 15:30:59.675 ThreadedObjects Clicked.

I should be getting messages telling me that the Threader object was created, and that it is preparing to launch a background thread, that the thread has been spawned and then after 10 seconds, that the thread is done running. 
So, where's my glaring obvious error?

Comment: I'd suggest you dive deep on Objective-C;  your naming conventions indicate a C++ background.   Also, if you are writing NEW concurrent code, consider using NSOperationQueue or GCD instead of threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` isn't a constructor, it's for setup after construction. You need the class object to create an instance before you can send `init`, and, most importantly, you need to assign the results to your variable.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    threadedObject = [[Threader alloc] init];
}
```

You can't send `alloc` to an object that's not a class; instances don't respond to it. The only reason that this isn't crashing is that globals are initialized to 0/`NULL`/`nil`, and `[nil someMessage]` does nothing.

Not assigning the results to your variable is the same as:

```
int x = 0;
x + 10;
```

There's no change to `x`'s value.

Additionally, you don't seem to have an ivar there, just a global variable. Ivars need to go into a curly-brace block at the head of the `@implementation`:

```
@implementation Threader
{
    Threader * threadedObject;
}

// etc...
```

Comment: I see, let me make a few changes then. Thank you for the clear response!

Answer (score 1):

You never **alloc** the object.............

Also, this is curious:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Threader.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)StartBackgroundThreadButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end


Threader* threadedObject;
```

Where exactly did you declare the threadedObject? Like above? Use an iVar
or, better, a property for it!

Comment: I had originally set threadedObject as a property, but I was still getting the same error. I had forgotten to add in alloc(I'll update that in the OP); but I am still running into the same error as before even though I reset it back to a property. If I remember correctly, properties do not need to use [[_property alloc] init] / [_property new]?

Comment: That's not correct, @DanielMartin: all objects need to be constructed. You may be confusing the fact that a property has a _variable_ created for it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of reactions:

1. Show us where your definition and alloc/init of `threadedObject`.
2. I'm not sure what business problem you're trying to solve, but this smells like the precursor of some custom `NSOperation` solution. Operation queues are ideally suited for these sorts of implementations.

   I'd be inclined to subclass `NSOperation` when trying to do something like this. See the [custom NSOperation object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW16) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide.*
3. I'd suggest using camelCase for your method and variable names.
4. If you say with this, I'd steer you away from the "thread" name, as it might imply that you're doing something with `NSThread`, which you're not.

Comment: Risking a guess, I would think that OP is jut "experimenting" a bit to learn the language, and not trying to have some production code. Speculation though